# Docker - passing uid:gid to --user argument on windows

Tags: python, windows, docker

I am trying to get a docker container up and running on my windows machine. The project that provides the docker container also provides a small python script which selects configuration and formats arguments before using them to run `docker run ...`  with all of the appropriate arguments. I'm trying to modify the script slightly to work with windows and ran into the following error when providing the `--user` argument:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: unable to find user username: no matching entries in passwd file.
```

I know that according to [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user) if you pass a username, the user must exist in the container which is obviously why I am getting the error. The orginal script before I modified it sets `--user` to `uid:gid` (which it fetches in the script using `os.geteuid()` and `os.getegid()`.

These commands are only for linux however and of course `uid`, `pid`, `gid` are all unix concepts. What can I pass to `--name` on windows such that my user doesn't have to exist in the container.

Comment: Why do you need to pass a `--user` option? What issue is it solving for you? What user does the image specify by default?